# Creating a calculated member containing the number of years between two dates

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, reportbuilder3.0

I have a cube with two dates - `Date of Birth` and `Date of Purchase`. I would like to create a **calculated member** which produces the `age in years` based on these two dates. I can already do this in the dataset once the query has been run however I would like to include all empty values as I have a layout based on showing all the blanks as well as the "used" values.

Can someone give me an example of how to calculate this in MDX as running with the two date sets currently causes memory issues.

Comment: What do you mean by 'two dates', it's two fields of some table/view in Data Source View? Are there dimensions on these fields? Could you please add an example of data rows and expected results to be on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

A Basic Idea. This returns only one measure when two dates are given.

Please modify it as per your necessity.

```
With 
Member NumOfDays As
{[Date].[Calendar Month Date].[Date].&[19850101]:[Date].[Calendar Month Date].[Date].&[19870927]}.Count
Member TotalYears As NumOfDays/365
Member Years As Int(TotalYears)
Member YearParts As TotalYears - Years
Member TotalMonths As (YearParts * 12)
Member Months As Int(TotalMonths)
Member MonthParts As TotalMonths - Months
Member Days As Int(MonthParts * 30)
Member Age As CSTR(Years) + " years, " + CSTR(Months) + " months and " + CSTR(Days) + " days"

Select 
{NumOfDays, TotalYears, Years, YearParts, TotalMonths, Months, MonthParts, Days, Age}

On 0
From [Adventure Works]
```

The output should come as below.

[image]